# How do you change a variable in a KSH if or case statement?

Tags: variables, if-statement, ksh

Does anyone know how to set a variable with global scope in a KSH if, case, or loop statement?

I am trying to run the following code but the script only echo's "H" instead of the actual value seen in the input file.

```
CFG_DIR=${WORK_DIR}/cfg
CFG_FILE=${CFG_DIR}/$1
NAME=$(echo $CFG_FILE | cut -f1 -d\.)

UPPER_BUS_NETWORK="H"

cat ${CFG_FILE} | grep -v ^\# |
while read CLINE
do
    PROPERTY=$(echo $CLINE | cut -f1 -d\=)
    VALUE=$(echo $CLINE | cut -f2 -d\=)

    if [ ${PROPERTY} = "UpperBusService" ]; then
        UPPER_BUS_SERVICE="${VALUE}"
    fi
    if [ ${PROPERTY} = "UpperBusNetwork" ]; then
        UPPER_BUS_NETWORK="${VALUE}"
    fi
done

echo ${UPPER_BUS_NETWORK}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're running that in ksh? Which version? Ksh93 doesn't set up a subshell in a `while` loop. Bash, dash, ash and **pdksh** do, though. I'm not sure about ksh88.

Compare

```
$ bash -c 'a=111; echo foo | while read bar; do echo $a; a=222; echo $a; done; echo "after: $a"'
111
222
after: 111
```

to

```
ksh -c 'a=111; echo foo | while read bar; do echo $a; a=222; echo $a; done; echo "after: $a"'
111
222
after: 222
```

Zsh gives the same result as ksh93.

Unfortunately, pdksh doesn't support process substitution and ksh93 does, but not when redirected into the `done` of a `while` loop, so the usual solution which works in Bash is not available. This is what it would look like:

```
# Bash (or Zsh)
while read ...
do
    ...
done < <(command)
```

Using a temporary file may be the only solution:

```
command > tmpfile
while read
do
    ...
done < tmpfile
```

Some additional notes:

- Instead of `cat ${CFG_FILE} | grep -v ^\#` do `grep -v ^\# "${CFG_FILE}"`
- Usually, you should use `read -r` so backslashes are handled literally
- Instead of `NAME=$(echo $CFG_FILE | cut -f1 -d\.)` you should be able to do something like `NAME=${CFG_FILE%%.*}` and `VALUE=${#*=}; VALUE=${VALUE%%=*}`
- Variables should usually be quoted on output, for example in *each* of your echo statements and your `cat` command
- I recommend the habit of using lowercase or mixed case variable names to avoid conflict with shell variables (though none are present in your posted code)